# Homogeneous linear DE with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here are some question from book, I have to answer with "yes" or "no":

a)  $\phi(x)=x^{2}+3$ is solution of some homogeneous linear DE with constant coefficiens,

b)  $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2+x^{2}}$ is solution of some homogeneous linear DE with constant coefficiens.

Answer on a) should be "yes" (I found DE y'''=0) and "no" on b). Is it ok?

Comment: yes and yes. more characters

Comment: Why "yes" on b) ?

Comment: No, yes as in I agree with your "no". The only solutions to constant coefficient ODEs in homogeneous case are just polynomials, exponentials, sines, cosines and products and sums thereof.